# Google wave: PDF-generation (pdfjet)

Tags: google-app-engine, pdf-generation, google-wave

PDFjet says it supports App Engine, which by extension means it will run on Wave. e question is how can I get to to work on the Google WavE?

The goal is to get a PDF-button in the wave which is able to output the whole wave into PDF

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You'll likely need to do the following:

1. Write a [wave robot](http://code.google.com/apis/wave/extensions/robots/index.html) that simply joins a wave so it's capable of copying its contents.
2. Write a [wave gadget](http://code.google.com/apis/wave/extensions/gadgets/guide.html) that adds an 'As PDF' button to a wave. When clicked, it should make a call to your bot directly, returning the generated PDF.
3. Write an [extension installer](http://code.google.com/apis/wave/extensions/installers/#ExtensionHooks) that installs the robot and gadget in a wave.
4. Implement code to render a wave to a PDF using PDFJet. Since PDFJet doesn't render HTML to PDFs directly, you'll either need to implement your own renderer, or use [another](http://itextpdf.com/) [library](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/).